# DialogBoxW Not working in DLL but work in exe

Tags: c++, dll, dialog

I've been trying to create a DLL which creates a dialog. When I compile it into an executable, the dialog shows, but when I try to compile it into a DLL the dialog does not show.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK SubDiag(HWND hDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
        break;

    default:
        return FALSE;
        break;
    }

    return false;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainDiag(HWND hDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:

        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case ID_Button:
            DialogBoxW(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDD_SUB), hDlg, DLGPROC(SubDiag));
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
        break;

    default:
        return FALSE;
        break;
    }

    return false;
}

DWORD WINAPI Thread(LPVOID dwParam)
{
    HWND _hwnd = CreateDialogW(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), NULL, DLGPROC(MainDiag));
    ShowWindow(_hwnd, SW_SHOW);

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (IsWindow(_hwnd) && GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!IsDialogMessage(_hwnd, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't this work in the DLL?

Comment: The code required to show the dialog must vary between the executable and the DLL. It might be useful to show those differences as well.

Comment: Where is the code that tells the DLL to start the thread the shows the dialog?

Comment: Where does `hInst` come from?

Comment: //for DLL
    BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if(dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        {
            hInst = hModule;
            CreateThread(NULL, NULL, Thread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

    //For Exe
    int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
    {
     hInst = hInstance;
     return Thread(hInst);
    }

Comment: hard to adjust comment sorry.

Comment: You should call `GetLastError()` if `CreateDialogW` fails. If the Dialog Resource is still in the EXE, you should pass NULL, not hInst.

Comment: QuantumDumbAss, Please add new information to the question next time around, not as a comment ('cos it's hard to read).  Thx. @manuel: GDI and USER32 functions don't generally set LastError.  But I think you might be right about `hInst', only the OP knows where the dialog resource actually resides.

Comment: @PaulSanders `CreateDialog` sets LastError. If the ressource is not found, you will get 1813 `ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND`. A bunch of User32 functions set LastError.

Comment: @manuell, OK, thanks.  Useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

Does the dialog resource reside in the application or the DLL?

If it resides in the application, then you need to do:

```
DialogBoxW (NULL, ...);
```

But if it resides in the DLL then you need to do:

```
DialogBoxW (hInst, ...);
```

Where `hInst` is set to the value of `hinstDLL` passed to [`DllMain()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Dlls/dllmain) when `dwReason` == `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` (as you show in your comment).

Also, that call to `CreateThread ()` in your `DllMain` looks mighty suspicious.  What's the deal with that? (Please add the information to your question, thank you).